# Show picklist field in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a picklist field on Account I have put some values in that field. I want to show this field in the lightning page but I don't have idea how to show this in the Lightning component.

find my code below:

```
 <aura:attribute name="newaccount" type="Account" 
               default="{'sobjectType': 'Account',
                  'Name': '',  
                  'Phone': '',
                  'Number_1st__c':'',
                  'Number_2nd__c':'',
                  'Total_No_addition__c':'',
                  'Choose_City__c':'',
                  'Account_create':''}"/>
```

Choose_City__c is a picklist

if I used below tag. It keeps on loading put screenshot.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
        <force:inputField value="{!v.newaccount.Choose_City__c}"/>
</div>
```

[image]

if I use

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <lightning:input aura:id="city" type="String" label="Select City" 
                                 value="{!v.newaccount.Choose_City__c}"/>
```

It is showing as text field.

Comment: <lightning:input doesntt have picklist support as of now. force:inputField gets stuck in loading stage if you have not spelled the field name properly.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1. Do it using **lightning:select** where you describe set of options.
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm

   ```
   <aura:component>
   <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item" onchange="{!c.doSomething}">
       <option value="">choose one...</option>
       <option value="1">one</option>
       <option value="2">two</option>
   </lightning:select>
   </aura:component>
   ```
2. A better option will be to use `<force:inputField>`
   It will automatically determine the type and show checkbox, picklist or text field.

   ```
   <aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" 
              default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account' }"/>

   Account Name: <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}"/><br></br>
   Ratings:  <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Risk_Rating__c}"/><!-- My picklist Field-->

   </aura:application>
   ```

   [image]
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_inputField.htm

Comment: It is showing as input text field

Comment: Added my tested code and screenshot. If you are still facing issue can you edit the main question and add the code you tried, we would then be able to help you debug.

Comment: Updated my question and code. Please find